# nohup append the executed command at the top of the output file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Let's say that we invoke the `nohup` in the following way:

```
nohup foo.py -n 20 2>&1 &
```

This will write the output to the `nohup.out`.
How could we achieve to have the whole command `nohup foo.py -n 20 2>&1 &` sitting at the top of the `nohup.out` (or any other specified output file) after which the regular output of the executed command will be written to that file?

The reason for this is for purely debugging purpose as there will be thousands of commands like this executed and very often some of them will crash due to various reasons. It's like a basic report kept in a file with the executed command written at the top followed by the output of the executed command.

Comment: Including `2>&1 &` makes your problem a lot more complicated than it would be otherwise, as that directive isn't part of the command itself as such, but rather an instruction for the shell about redirections to be performed before it starts running the command at all, and whether to `wait` for its completion. Capturing `foo.py -n 20` on its own is far more straightforward.

Comment: btw, I assume you'd be okay with an answer that doesn't actually use nohup at all, as long as it achieves the same effect? (`nohup` doesn't do much of value; `nohup foo &` is essentially identical to `foo </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 & disown -h "$!"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I would accept every solution that captures the command and the output even if it does not include the nohup command itself. That's something I inherited from somebody else and now it clearly needs a change. :D

Comment: BTW, for purposes of preserving a command's context to reproduce later, think about also logging the current working directory and the set of active environment variables. When I've done this in the past I had several different output files (one for the environment, one with the command line in NUL-delimited format, etc, one for stdout, etc), and in that context saving the environment was as simple as making a copy of `/proc/self/environ`. NUL-delimited file formats are particularly useful here because any language can parse them correctly; whereas parsing shell syntax can be more interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward alternative would be something like:

```
myNohup() {
  (
    set +m                         # disable job control
    [[ -t 0 ]] && exec </dev/null  # redirect stdin away from tty
    [[ -t 1 ]] && exec >nohup.out  # redirect stdout away from tty
    [[ -t 2 ]] && exec 2>&1        # redirect stderr away from tty
    set -x                         # enable trace logging of all commands run
    "$@"                           # run our arguments as a command
  ) & disown -h "$!"               # do not forward any HUP signal to the child process
}
```

To define a command we can test this with:

```
waitAndWrite() { sleep 5; echo "finished"; }
```

...and run:

```
myNohup waitAndWrite
```

...will return immediately and, after five seconds, leave the following in `nohup.out`:

```
+ waitAndWrite
+ sleep 5
+ echo finished
finished
```

If you only want to write the exact command run without the side effects of xtrace, replace the `set -x` with (assuming bash 5.0 or newer) `printf '%s\n' "${*@Q}"`.

For older versions of bash, you might instead consider `printf '%q ' "$@"; printf '\n'`.

---

This does differ a little from what the question proposes:

- Redirections and other shell directives are not logged by `set -x`. When you run `nohup foo 2>&1 &`, the `2>&1` is not passed as an argument to `nohup`; instead, it's something the shell does *before `nohup` is started*. Similarly, the `&` is not an argument but an instruction to the shell not to `wait()` for the subprocess to finish before going on to future commands.

Comment: Thank you, I'll test it asap and see how it goes. Could I safely use it witch `sbatch` for SLURM? That is the true goal.

Comment: I haven't worked with slurm, so it's not something I'm in a position to speak to.